# Integrating Google TAg Manager with Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, gtm

Can we integrate GTM to aura components? I Have LWC components that are wrapped in Aura components with 40+ API versions. I need to just count the page hits on my app(Web/Mobile). Will it be possible to achieve this now? As I am not getting any of the documentation for this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Have you tried, or are you just asking if it's possible? If you did try, how far did you get? Do you have any code you can share with us?

Comment: Hey.!! Thanks !! I have created one GTM account and then added the script as static resource in the org. and then included that script in the aura component. i dont know the further steps and also did not get any documentation about the same. Would really appreciate the help.